# Retrieve complete list of music genres

Tags: android, gracenote

I was wondering if there was a way to get the list of all top music genres(level-0) using the GNSDK mobile client library on Android . We are trying to match those music genres with our internal music genres . That is why we would like to retrieve the entire list of music genres in advance.  I saw the question been ask before but the answer was unclear to me. In the documentation of GNSDK mobile, I read this: "Gracenote-definednumericidentifiervalueistypicallya5-digitvalue;forexample,the genre identifier 24045 for Rock.These identifiers are maintained in lists in Gracenote Service; download the lists using GNSDK for Mobile Manager's Lists and List Types APIs" but I was not able to find that list type API. Can I please have the name of the method that I should call and the name of the Class where that method is located ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android the type to use is GnList (com.gracenote.gnsdk.GnList).
Create an object of that kind and use it's method to retrieve what you need. It's just a list. Iterate over its elements.

If you are looking for a sample, you could download GNSDK instead that has more examples and one of them is retrieving the Genres. It's not exactly the same but will show you the different calls to make.